# Is it possible to get ip address of VM's without installing ESXI tools?

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere, esxi

I am using vSphere client to get informations from the installed VM.
I have gone through the following link :
http://benohead.com/getting-info-from-your-esx-server-using-the-vmware-infrastructure-vsphere-java-api-part-1/

and managed to get which ip's are up/down. I need the IP address.There is no tools installed. Is it possible to get IP address without installing Esxi tool?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the VMware tools if you would like to fetch the IP address. But without installing the VMware Tools there is an another way to fetch the IP address by using VM Name

In `VirtualMachineConfigInfo` class, `getName()` will return the VM Name or by using  `vm.config.name` will return VM name and then pass the VM name to the below code

```
String ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(<<VIRTUALMACHINENAME>>).getHostAddress();
```

Note: This code will works only if the host name is resolvable.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it isn't. If it was, that'd break the whole illusion of virtualization.

There is another way, though, but it requires instrumenting the VMs. If you can install an agent inside the VM that broadcasts/pings it's IP to the outside world through some mechanism, that'd be a solution. Can't think of any other way you can get the IP of a machine. Not through the vsphere sdk definitely.